# The page is unable to handle request. running php on localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I am running this code on localhost. there is an error while running on http://localhost:8000/Polymorphism.php . It's a simple polymorphism code on php. Other codes are easily running but there is an error running this code.

This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

```
<?php


public interface Shape{

   public function calculateArea();


} 

 public class Circle implements Shape{

  private $radius;


  public function __construct($r){
   $this->radius=$r;
  }

  public function calculateArea(){

  echo 'Area of circle = '.pi()* $this->radius*$this->radius.'<br>';

  }
}

class Rectangle implements Shape{

 private $height;
 private $width;

 public function __construct($h,$w){
  this->height=$h;
  this->width=$w;
 }

 public function calculateArea(){
 echo 'Area of a Rectangle=' .$this->height.$this->width.'<br>';
 }

 }

 $circle= new Circle(5);
 $rect= new Rectangle(10,20);


 $circle->calculateArea();
 $rect->calculateArea();


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign access modifiers to the classes or interfaces.They are only used to specific the methods and properties. And you have two more mistakes in class `Rectangle` where  you should mention height and width as

```
  $this->height=$h;
  $this->width=$w;
```

**Change your overall code to**

```
<?php
interface Shape{

 public function calculateArea();

} 

class Circle implements Shape{

  private $radius;


  public function __construct($r){
   $this->radius=$r;
 }

 public function calculateArea(){

  echo 'Area of circle = '.pi()* $this->radius*$this->radius.'<br>';

}
}

class Rectangle implements Shape{

 private $height;
 private $width;

 public function __construct($h,$w){
  $this->height=$h;
  $this->width=$w;
}

public function calculateArea(){
 echo 'Area of a Rectangle=' .$this->height.$this->width.'<br>';
}

}

$circle= new Circle(5);
$rect= new Rectangle(10,20);

$circle->calculateArea();
$rect->calculateArea();
?>
```